# iOS app crashes when quickly tapping tab bar buttons

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using tab bar in app.

If i tap the tabs quickly then app crashes with below error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Each tab points to a view controller that fetches data from parse backend. Fetch doesnt happen always in viewDidAppear() or viewDidLoad(). happens only if loading first time or on pull to refresh so simply changing tabs does not result in fetch from Parse if view was loaded once. I am suspecting parse because it allows one query at a time on one object so may be switching tab quickly causes another query execution and fails.

I got error network operation already in process error couple of times but console doesnt show anything more than above error most of times.

Some posts suggested to check whether outlets are delinked due to rename/delete, storyboard ids missing. I checked and found nothing missing.

I tried to cancel parse query on viewWillDisappear() in these view controllers but noticed duplicate records being loaded couple of times so doesnt seem to be clean solution.

**Update :**
**This is another place where i am getting same error of network operation already in progress**

this is sample code where it seems to fail. Doesn't outer query execution gets over by the time inner query.findObjectsInBackground() starts?

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "user")
        query.whereKeyExists("friends")

        query.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
            if error == nil {
                calculateNoOfPages(count)

                query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (friends, error) in

                    if error == nil {
                            //handle array

                    }  else {

                        //handle error
                    }

                })
            } else {

                //handle error
            }

        }
```

As solution to above, i create another query variable with same conditions and use for internal find operation. is this is correct workaround?

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: Set an "Exception Breakpoint" for all exceptions

Comment: https://github.com/RedRoma/SwiftExceptionCatcher

Comment: @Gereon xcode stopped at a thread Queue:SQLQueue. I am not using CoreData. Could this is behind the scene call by Parse API? What do i do nex?t

Comment: From this you should be able to figure out what the last thing in your code was that led to the exception.

Comment: @Gereon  i found another place where it is happening. I have updated my question with sample code.